# Need To Ship Multiple Products with 1 Shipping Cost (by Category or Volume)

Tags: checkout, shipping, magento-community, shipping-methods, multishipping

I have multiple products (books) and need to combine shipping cost on checkout. 
*(example: buy one comic book - shipping costs $5.65 - but I can also fit another 20 items from the same Category in the shipping package with no additional shipping cost)*

Some items are small and can be fit into the same shipment for a flat rate at no additional cost, up to a certain number of items / volume of the total package sent.

Currently it is "per product" shipping cost. I do not need to bill customers per product for shipping when I can fit multiple items into one shipment for the same price.

I do not wish to purchase any extensions. I need either a free extension that will solve this, or advice on how to write the code in Magento please.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be handled by tablerates. You have to find a system with the weight to map it to the different levels of shipping costs.

Like:
Comic book, weight: 1

costs for weight: 0-100: 30€

So you can purchaes 100 comic books for 30€ shipping costs, but when you buy a book (weight: 50) you can only purchase 2.